# OpenJPA update query, error: Expression "UPDATEVALUE" requires at least one child

Tags: java, sql, jpa, openjpa

I have a named query like this:

```
UPDATE Table t SET t.status = :statusTo, t.something = null 
WHERE t.status = :statusFrom AND t.lastStatusUpdate <= :lastStatusUpdate
```

This query works perfectly fine when I run it in SQL Developer, but not when my application tries to run it. Before executing the query the 3 parameters are set ofcourse. I get the following error when my application runs it:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: An error occurred while parsing 
the query filter "query here". Error message: Expression "UPDATEVALUE" requires
at least one child.;
```

While google'ing my problem, the only result that more or less was the same as my situation was a bug report from almost 6 years ago, where updating to a null value didn't work. That page mentions that it should be resolved, and my OpenJPA version should be more recent.

OpenJPA version is 1.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message kind of threw me in the wrong direction at first. The problem was indeed the "= null" part of the query.

I fixed the query like this:

```
t.something = :something
```

And then the parameter like this:

```
query.setParameter("something", null);
```